# Cannot validate SAML assertion signature

Tags: digital-signature, keystore, saml, saml-2.0, josso

I am Service Provide receiving a SAML assertion signature from the IDP. I am using JOSSO on top of Tomcat to consume the assertion. Issue here is that I cannot validate the assertion signature.

The IDP cert is uploaded into my keystore, using an alias "IDP".

When validating the sig, I get the following error:

```
2012-12-19 14:09:38,697 | ERROR | P/SAML2/ACS/POST | AbstractCamelProducer            | tion.camel.AbstractCamelProducer  146 | 170 - org.atricore.idbus.kernel.main - 1.3.0 | urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied:urn:org:atricore:idbus:samlr2:status:**InvalidResponseSignature:null**:
org.atricore.idbus.capabilities.sso.support.core.SSOResponseException: urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:RequestDenied:urn:org:atricore:idbus:samlr2:status:InvalidResponseSignature:null:

at org.atricore.idbus.capabilities.sso.main.sp.producers.AssertionConsumerProducer.validateResponse(AssertionConsumerProducer.java:943)

at org.atricore.idbus.capabilities.sso.main.sp.producers.AssertionConsumerProducer.doProcess(AssertionConsumerProducer.java:139)

at org.atricore.idbus.capabilities.sso.main.sp.producers.AssertionConsumerProducer.doProcess(AssertionConsumerProducer.java:85)

at org.atricore.idbus.kernel.main.mediation.camel.AbstractCamelProducer.process(AbstractCamelProducer.java:133)[170:org.atricore.idbus.kernel.main:1.3.0]

at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:43)[148:org.apache.camel.camel-core:1.6.1]
```

Why can't JOSSO detect the certificate in the keystore and validate the signature? Do I need to define the alias differently?

Comment: This is a known bug in JOSSO.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in JOSSO. Awaiting workaround from support

Comment: Do you know the exact issue? It could be useful to attach the link here. Thanks